# "Hashcode" for string alphabetic comparision

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting

Is it possible to device "hash-code" that grows with alphabetic position of the string? The goal is more effective comparison-based algorithms.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Surt In order to sort array of strings you perform, for example, (n log n) comparisons of of strings. Is it possible. under certain condition, pre-calculate some "checksum" for strings, that comparison of the checksum return same result that comparison between origin strings.

Comment: Except when the hash of two different strings returns the same value. So what you are searching for is a compression that maintains the same lexicographic order as the strings themselves?

Comment: @Surt Yes. You have phrased it perfectly.